# How can I automatically start the Safari Reader?

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

Is there a way to tell Safari to automatically use Reader when it recognizes an article which it is able to display with Reader?

Right now I have to manually click the Reader button at the right side of the address bar.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to figure this out myself, and haven't yet come up with a way to load `safari-resource:/Reader.html` programmatically.

If necessary, I fall back to [Readability](http://lab.arc90.com/experiments/readability/), the 3rd-party Safari add-on Apple used as their basis for Reader. Combined with [Safari Stand](http://hetima.com/safari/stand-e.html), I can modify the appearance of pages when they load.

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain your issue with my answer?

Comment: Wow, the Readability is absolutely awesome! Thanks Dori

Comment: @senlamy - glad to hear you like it! If it works for you, please consider accepting my answer.

Comment: By the way, Readabilty has just been dramatically improved - http://blog.readability.com/2011/01/the-new-readability/

Answer (score 2):

Try <kbd>CMD + SHFT + R</kbd> to save the effort of the precision mouse motion.

Comment: Yes, I know about that, but I wanted something automated and the "Readibility" bookmark as posted by Dori is absolutely bombastic, since it Safari Reader doesn't work on all sites.

Answer (score 1):

I've built a Safari extension for this. Download it from here:

http://finbarrbrady.com/2013/09/auto-reader-for-safari/

Comment: Hi @Fin, thanks for your first answer, and thanks for attributing your involvement in the product you link to clearly (we are getting a lot of self-promotion spam, although this looks fair to me).